# Real time updation in front end when changes occur in database

Tags: database, firebase-realtime-database, frontend, web-frontend

How to update front end ui when database records updates or changes

Example 
Twitter 
Twitter post dynamically gets increased no of likes

What is the technology we shall use for this kind of real time updates and what is the way

Another example firebase 
When something updates in firebase records 
Automatically front end ui updates

Please could someone help me to crack this

Comment: Have you looked at AJAX?

Comment: Yes I'm aware of Ajax , but the point is how to implement in such a way when database records changes we need to get the latest data ? Thanks for the quick response

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995/is-there-some-way-to-push-data-from-web-server-to-browser

Answer (score 3):

There are many solutions for pushing data from a server to a (web) client. Some examples from Firebase:

- Firebase's Realtime Database SDKs use Web Sockets for maintaining its connection between client and server.
- When you access Firebase Realtime Database using its REST API, you can use server-sent events (SSE) to accomplish streaming updates.
- Cloud Firestore uses long-polling requests over HTTP/2. There are many solutions for this type of connection.

Some more reading:

- [Is there some way to PUSH data from web server to browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19995/is-there-some-way-to-push-data-from-web-server-to-browser)
- [How can a server send an update without a client request?](https://www.quora.com/How-can-a-server-send-an-update-without-a-client-request)
- [HTML push data from server to client updates without polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617004/html-push-data-from-server-to-client-updates-without-polling) (no answer, but the question contains some relevant links)
- [How to push live data from nodejs server to AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077909/how-to-push-live-data-from-nodejs-server-to-angularjs)
- and probably more from these [search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+push+update+from+server+to+client)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference , I'll go through all these , if I find any solution then I'll mark this as an answer , I appreciate your help