# how to update data from database dynamically to chart(highchart) using springboot

Tags: java, spring, database

I'm trying to show charts getting data from database. And I want the graph to be dynamic. I'm currently using mysql workbench and whenever I insert or delete any data from mysql workbench I want the chart to change automatically without refreshing the page.
please check my code below
First of all Controller class I passing my database data with model.addAttribute and will use in dailyUpdate.html

**Controller.java**

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Controller
public class Controller {
    private final StatusService statusService;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getData(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("statusDTO", statusService.getFacilityStatus());
        return "daily/dailyUpdate";
    }

}
```

Below is my dailyUpdate.html code

**dailyUpdate.html**

```java
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<th:block th:replace="~{/layout/basic :: setContent(~{this::content} )}">

    <th:block th:fragment="content">

        <div class="container">
            <span>
                <div id="buildingStatus">


                  </div>
                <table id="datatable">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>In</th>
                        <th>Out</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                     <th:block th:each="num: ${#numbers.sequence(0,9)}">
                         <tr>
                             <th>[[${statusDTO.getBName()[num]}]]</th>
                             <td>[[${statusDTO.getIn()[num]}]]</td>
                             <td>[[${statusDTO.getOut()[num]}]]</td>
                         </tr>

                     </th:block>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </span>

        </div>

        <script th:inline="javascript">

        

            Highcharts.chart('buildingStatus', {
                data: {
                    table: 'datatable'
                },
                chart: {
                    type: 'column',
                },
                title: {
                    text: '건물 출입 현황'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    allowDecimals: false,
                    title: {
                        text: '명수'
                    }
                },
                credits:{
                    enabled:false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                            this.point.y + ' ' + this.point.name.toLowerCase();
                    }
                }
            });

        </script>


    </th:block>

</th:block>
```

and if i run the app it will show this
[view of the app after running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7rHv.png)

now What I want to do actually is that whenever the database data changes(like if I change insert or delete data into mysql workbench as it shows in below picture) I want the bar chart to change automatically without refreshing the page. Can you tell me how to do this?.. I'm really having a hard time making this work. Please help me

[mysql workbench data picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAnfJ.png)

Comment: This question was answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60998379/real-time-updation-in-front-end-when-changes-occur-in-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out. I was choosing among using ajax, websocket and firebase.
I acutally used websocket to solve the problem.